# use error middleware when using express.Router

Tags: node.js, express

I want to use express.Router in my app.
I have a file index file that runs the server.
And a file routes that run some express routes, thanks to express.Router.

What I want that, whenever one of my route fails, the error middleware defined in index is reached;

In the example above:
- when I use the route ok, it works
- when I use the route no ok, the error is thrown without reaching the error middleware.

Do you know how to achieve it ?

Thank you !

[https://gist.github.com/VivienAdnot/e3cf44de745531c6cca7be5de53c341a](http://gist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js (Express) error handling middleware with router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356705/node-js-express-error-handling-middleware-with-router)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I can see that you are missing the 'next' argument in the error-handler middleware, since 'next' is required to pass the control to the next matching route. Just change the middleware code in **index.js** to,

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('error mw reached');
    res.status(500);
    res.end();
    next();
});
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

My error middleware was bad-named ...

```
// doesn't work
app.use((err, req, res) => {
    console.log('error mw reached');
    res.status(500);
    res.end();
});
```

to:

```
//works
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('error mw reached');
    res.status(500);
    res.end();
});
```